# Hbase byteArray to Long

Tags: java, hbase, arrays, long-integer

I have a row key which is being created like this

```
Put put  = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(tweets.getContact_Unique_Id()+"^"+Bytes.toBytes(epoch)));
```

Where epoch is the long timestamp.

Now when I scan I get a row as

> 3857^[B@7c8f4424

Now I wish to convert the part of rowkey ie to Long

> [B@7c8f4424

How do I achieve this.

EDIT -> If I use the put as

> Put put  = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(tweets.getContact_Unique_Id() + "^"
>   + epoch);

Not all rows gets inserted , but when I use

> Put put  = new
>   Put(Bytes.toBytes(tweets.getContact_Unique_Id()+"^"+Bytes.toBytes(epoch)));

All rows gets inserted , please note that all time values are different.

Also note I have used "^" to seperate out the 1st and 2nd part of rowkey.

Thanks

Comment: to edit: what does it mean "not all rows gets inserted"? exceptions on writing? nothing on getting row by key? have you checked that all keys unique?

Comment: Yes all rows should be unique as there are different time stamps, there are no exceptions , I have also used System.currentTimeMillis(); and then incrementing the epoch each time before insert but with the Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(tweets.getContact_Unique_Id() + "^" + epoch); , not all rows are somehow unique but the put i have used in my question it works but now i'm unable to retrieve the original long timestamp

Comment: fast solution:
byte[] epoBytes = Bytes.toBytes(epoch);
Put put  = new Put(Bytes.add(Bytes.toBytes(tweets.getContact_Unique_Id() + "^" + epoBytes), epoBytes));

the better solution is to be more accurate dealing with current time. i have no your full code so i can't give you more accurate advice about it.

Comment: Hi thanks again , all the rows are getting inserted but now I'm getting the rowkey as 918^[B@5c731511\x00\x00\x01S\x95\xCA\xCB\xE8 , now do I extract the original timestamp value from this ?

Comment: see my main answer, i provided decoding. and if it works fine please accept the answer)

Comment: Yes it will work , but I have to decode this string  "\x00\x00\x01T.\xBA\x06\xC0" but while storing it as a string / byte array variable it says I have to remove invalid escape characters. Any suggestion on that. I have accepted the answer :)

Comment: You can store it like you stored before:
byte[] epoBytes = Bytes.toBytes(epoch);
new Put(Bytes.toBytes(tweets.getContact_Unique_Id() + "&" + epoBytes + "^" + epoch);

Comment: Thanks now I got the rowkey as 9&[B@2ddc38b3^1463535294000 , Now I directly got my timestamp :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ***save*** your long value in **a wrong way**!

Because when you use `+` your array with bytes of the long value converts to string, the converted value shows **the current address in memory** of the bytes array, **not** its **value**!

---

The correct way of saving:

```
Put put  = new Put(Bytes.add(Bytes.toBytes(tweets.getContact_Unique_Id() + "^"), Bytes.toBytes(epoch))); //I kept "^", don't know why you need it
```

And retrieving:

```
// row is the byte array of your key
// Bytes.tail(..) gets tail of key's bytes with bytes of your long
// Bytes.toLong(..) converts long bytes to long
// 8 corresponds to long size in bytes
Bytes.toLong(Bytes.tail(row, 8))
```

Comment: byte[] bit = "[B@40dea6bc".getBytes();  System.out.println(Bytes.toLong(Bytes.tail(bit, 8)));  This is not giving correct result

Comment: In Java 8 you can use `Long.BYTES` instead of 8.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the answer but for some reason when I use the put which you have given , it skips some of the import to Hbase , that was the reason I used the put as mentioned in my question. So is there any way ?

Comment: what does it mean it skips? maybe you use the same epoch and tweets id several times and thus the key is not unique (and switching for old key construction "helps" because any time you create new bytes array for long and thus it has new address which became part of the key)? anyway it's not clear what and why happens from information that has been provided.